# How to handle deadlock situation in SSIS?

Tags: ssis-2012

In my `SSIS` package, I have two data flow tasks and those are accessing same table. While I am running the package at that time, I am facing some deadlock issues, How to handle this situation in our `SSIS` Packages?

Comment: What u mean by `some deadlock issues`, that is natural behaviour of SQL to protect referential integrity. Lot of factors should be considered ex: dataflow task (alternative to sample DML operations), use merge instead etc. You can only avoid read-write conflicts with (TABLOCKX).https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fbc8f303-3dad-42f2-9066-bbb01cab9f81/tsql-table-locks-during-transaction-probably-maybe?forum=transactsql

Comment: Please provide further info. For eg: Why are you accessing same table in